# How to create horizontal JLabels in GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm having an issue with the `GridLayout` in Java using Window Maker.

[image: Window with GridLayout]

I'm trying to create this window that will add `JLabel` info of a person with its name, age, etc.

The problem is that I'm using this grid layout because it will make the window much better, but every time I insert a label, it takes all the space down to the bottom of the window, and I just want it to take the text so I can later add more labels with a for loop.

Is there a way to add these labels with a certain height? Because this is the parameter I'm having right now when creating one:

```
labelDireccion.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
```

So, what I want to do is limit the label to just one row. The problem when talking about rows is that when I put more than one row in the window, it transforms into this:

[image: Window with GridLayout and 2 rows]

So, its basically that, any ideas?

Comment: Nest the JPanel in another JPanel that uses BorderLayout. Place this one in the outer's BorderLayout.PAGE_START (top) position.

Comment: Learning to combine and nest layouts is key to using Swing and other such layout-manager schemes.